# Changing from PHP to JS

Tags: php, javascript, html, input

My problem maybe is basic, i just lack the skills.
How can i turn the following code into javascript? :

```
    <?php
    for($i=1; $i<10; $i++){
        echo "<input type='text' placeholder='Word' name='word$i' /><br />";
    }
    ?>
```

I want to add an input everytime the user presses a button (already built) but i need every new input to have the following number than the one before. For instance:

input 1 (... name='word1')
*press again the button*
input 2 (... name='word2')
*press again the button*
input 3 (... name='word3')

Thanks! Happy 2013!

Comment: Do you want pure javascript, or jquery ? You should read up a bit on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Comment: Please be noted that PHP is executed at server side, while JavaScript is executed at client side. Your _end result_ seems very doable (and actually basic) with JavaScript, but the _output order_ will not be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Ok you have one button created please write a onclick event on it whick fires a function
like this and also create one main div in which your elements can be added

```
<input type="button" onclick="getElement();"/>
<di id="main"></div>
```

In the function getElement please write this code:

```
var i=1;
function getElement(){
var str = "<input type='text' placeholder='Word' name='word"+i+"' />";
i++;
document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  input.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Word');
  input.setAttribute('name', 'word' + i);
}
```

Something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Tested in Chrome

```
<input type="button" value="Magical pony time!" onclick="clickhandler()" />

<div id="container"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // contains the counter for elements added
    window.__buttonClickCounter = 0; 

    // Keep reference to container
   var c = document.getElementById('container');

    // Click handler that appends to the contents of the container
    var clickhandler = function() {
        c.innerHTML = c.innerHTML + "<input type='text' placeholder='Word' name='word"+window.__buttonClickCounter+"' value="+window.__buttonClickCounter+" /><br />";
        window.__buttonClickCounter++;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php
for($i=1; $i<10; $i++){
?>
<input type='text' placeholder='Word' name='word'<?php echo $i;?>/>
<?php
}
?>
```